# How do I change the xmlns in a new StartElement in C# with XMLWriter?

Tags: c#, xml

I need the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LIEFERUNG-AUSWI xmlns:aw="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bbk="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01 BbkXmwAuswi.xsd" version="1.0" erstellzeit="2013-11-06T15:36:44" stufe="Test" xmlns="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01">
  <ABSENDER xmlns="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01">
    <aw:FIRMENNR>00004711</aw:FIRMENNR>
...
```

My code is the following:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("LIEFERUNG-AUSWI", "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "aw", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "bbk", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01 BbkXmwAuswi.xsd");
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "version", null, "1.0");
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "erstellzeit", null, Dat_DatZeit);
writer.WriteAttributeString(null, "stufe", null, "Test");

// Start-Tag von Absender
writer.WriteStartElement("ABSENDER");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "bbk", null, "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01");
writer.WriteElementString("aw", "FIRMENNR", null, "00004711");
```

But this gives me the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LIEFERUNG-AUSWI xmlns:aw="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bbk="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01 BbkXmwAuswi.xsd" version="1.0" erstellzeit="2013-11-06T15:36:44" stufe="Test" xmlns="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01">
  <ABSENDER xmlns:bbk="http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01">
    <aw:FIRMENNR>00004711</aw:FIRMENNR>
```

What do I have to change to make `xmlns:bbk` become only `xmlns`? I never did something in XML so I am actually just trying but all I tried didn't work, either I got an error message or the result was wrong... here is something different I tried:

```
// Start-Tag von Absender
writer.WriteStartElement("ABSENDER", "http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01");
```

This gave me a wrong result...

Comment: Since you've already defined the URL in question as the namespace `bbk`, I'm not sure that the XmlWriter will be able to handle it being the default namespace later (basically, a namespace with two names). I might be wrong though.

Comment: @madd0 well what would you suggest? As I said i actually am just guessing how to write it so my whole code can be wrong... I don't even know if the first part of my code is right...

Comment: Why use `XmlWriter`? LINQ to XML is far easier.

Comment: @JohnSaunders sure but I know nothing about XML or LINQ and now it seems to work so I'll just leave it like that..

Comment: Sure but you're making it much more difficult to maintain. `XmlWriter` is a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the following line:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("ABSENDER");
```

to:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("", "ABSENDER","http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/2003-01-01");
```

The next one is unnecessary.

I may add that your XML seems a little overcomplicated, with namespaces being often redefined. For example in you root tag, *http://www.bundesbank.de/xmw/auswi/2003-01-01* is the default namespace, but it is also called *aw*, and the namespace that you called *bbk* is later used, without its name… Maybe you should consider simplifying your XML in the process.

Aside from that, not testing your code before posting will often get your question closed on SO. I recommend [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) for this. It's what I used to find your answer.

Comment: It worked, ty... Yes I know this looks a bit overcomplicated, but it has to look exactly like this, don't ask me why... We got the template so I can't change it...

Comment: And btw I tested my code, actually i tried something similar, but instead of `""` i tried with ´null´ for the prefix and this didn't work...